# upper/lower case naming convention for Document name in SPO Doc Lib

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, powershell, csom

I have a situation where users have uploaded several files but without any naming convention. So some of the file names are in upper case while some are in lower case . So Now I have to build a script that can read the file name from document library and then change the format to following convention: First letter of the word must be in caps and remaining letters in lower case. For example, if a file name is "construction monthly reports" or "CONSTRUCTION MONTHLY REPORTS" then it should be renamed to following: "Construction Monthly Reports".

Is this possible to do by leveraging some sort of a script? I am working with SharePoint online. If someone has come across this situation, can you please provide the solution you took. For now the app should be able to perform this change for all existing files, in future, whenever a file is uploaded then it must be renamed as per this rule.

Can someone help with a solution (Workflow, CSOM, JS etc.), if powershell is a solution then I will go with that as well. thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are in Online so I created a Flow which will do the work :) You can create another one, which will be started manualy and fix all existing documents, because I created it as for the new ones...

In SPO Library click on Flow and click **Create a flow**:
[image]

Click **See more** and select **When a new file is added in SharePoint, complete a custom action**:

[image]

Here is the flow, first create variables:

**Name** - Array - Value: `split(triggerBody()?['{FilenameWithExtension}'], ' ')`

[image]

**CorrectName** - String - Value: `Empty`

[image]

**Working** - String - Value: `Empty`

[image]

Create **Apply to Each** - Value: `variables('Name')`

**Set Variable** - Working - Value: `Current Item (will be displayed in Dynamic Content)`

**Append to string variable** - CorrectName - Value: `concat(' ', concat(toUpper(substring(variables('Working'),0,1)),toLower(substring(variables('Working'),1,add(length(variables('Working')),-1)))))`

[image]

**Set variable** - Working - Value: `substring(variables('CorrectName'),1,add(length(variables('CorrectName')),-1))`

**Send an HTTP request to SharePoint**:

- *You need to rename in URI List by Title - My is Migration*
- *You need to rename in Body: SP.Data.MigrationItem to yourItem (LibraryItem cause Migration is my library)*

  > ```
  > Method: POST
  > Uri: _api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Migration')/items(@{triggerBody()?['ID']})
  > Headers:
  >       Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
  >       IF-MATCH: * 
  >       X-HTTP-Method: MERGE
  > Body: {'__metadata':{'type':'SP.Data.MigrationItem'},'FileLeafRef':'@{variables('Working')}','Title':'@{variables('Working')}'}
  > ```

[image]

Whole Flow look like this:

[image]

**Here is my test:**

**Uploaded:**

[image]

**After Flow:**

[image]

*I hope you will like it! :) Zdeněk*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Wanted to confirm, in regards to the existing documents, should I just replaced the file created trigger with Manually trigger a flow trigger and keep the other action same as is, right? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you just do manually triger, at start load all files from this library (SharePoint - Get files (Properties Only)) and in Apply to Each, do this flow (constants must be initialized at start)

Comment: in this case you will need edit the Values where are triggerbody, which I post here, cause it will be a little different. There will be the foreach item instead.

Comment: I am getting an error: "The property '__metadata' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.Corporate_x0020_DocumentsItem'. My library name is "Corporate Documents" so that's the issue I guess, the http action is failing.

Comment: I have added some screenshots in question description of the flow run and my http re action, please take a look.

Comment: FIRST: Have you created library without space and after it renamed (i always doing this) so the "SP.Data.CorporateDocumentsItem" I tried flow with space and you have correct "SP.Data.Corporate_x0020_DocumentsItem". SECOND: Have you field Title in library or did you delete it?

Comment: Hi, I created library as "Corporate Documents"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88872/discussion-between-zdenk-vinduska-and-mdevm).

Comment: its an OOTB library created with space as Corporate Documents. Also I do have title field but i guess I am just using OOTB name field to populate, I have added screenshot of my library.

Comment: We have done this on TeamViewer, Now everything is functional. How i get the bounty? :D

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška The bounty is awarded when the open bounty ends to the (if any) accepted answer. As for now - 5 days. Nice answer btw. :) +1