# converting certain words in file name to upper case for all files in document libary

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, flow

I am looking for a powershell or may be flow approach to convert certain words used in Sharepoint file name to upper case. For example,a document library contains about 200 files. Each of these files may or may not contain words like Ln, Plc, Az etc.

The goal is to see if these words are present in the file name first and if so then convert them to upper case. So that way it can be converted into LN, PLC and AZ. This is something I want to perform on all existing files that reside in sharepoint online doc library. So looking for either powershell or flow approach to make it to work, or any other way if possible to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

look [HERE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256506/upper-lower-case-naming-convention-for-document-name-in-spo-doc-lib), I created Flow which doing exactly what you want few days ago.