# converting certain words in file name to upper case for all files in document libary

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, flow

I am looking for a powershell or may be flow approach to convert certain words used in Sharepoint file name to upper case. For example,a document library contains about 200 files. Each of these files may or may not contain words like Ln, Plc, Az etc.

The goal is to see if these words are present in the file name first and if so then convert them to upper case. So that way it can be converted into LN, PLC and AZ. This is something I want to perform on all existing files that reside in sharepoint online doc library. So looking for either powershell or flow approach to make it to work, or any other way if possible to do so.

This is a different question, its not a duplicate question. The requirement is different in this case, please read my question description. The question I had asked here was for the whole file name: [upper/lower case naming convention for Document name in SPO Doc Lib](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256506/upper-lower-case-naming-convention-for-document-name-in-spo-doc-lib/256607?noredirect=1#comment274314_256607). I am using this solution currently. But now i need another script or flow to catch certain words in the file name across the document library and only make them turn into upper case. thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting certain words in file name to upper case for all files in document libary](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256877/converting-certain-words-in-file-name-to-upper-case-for-all-files-in-document-li)

Comment: No its a different question, I have clearly mentioned it in the question description.

Answer (score 2):

use [this flow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256506/upper-lower-case-naming-convention-for-document-name-in-spo-doc-lib) i created few days ago, but in one thing, change to function:

**CHANGES:**

after some chat here is solution with dictionary for upper case words:

1. **Create Custom List** in SPO, only with Title. Fill Title with words you want to keep uppercase:

[image]

1. **Initialize another variable** UpperCaseCol at the start of the Flow which I referred here:
   [image]
2. **Get items from this** List with SharePoint Get Items function:
   [image]
3. Create Apply to Each before the existing one

   - Output from previous step: **Get items - value**
   - Set Variable: Working with **Get items - Title**
   - Append to string - Name: **UpperCaseCol**, Value: `concat(toUpper(variables('Working')),',')`

[image]

1. Edit Apply to each - existing from the referred flow, edit the body

   - Insert Condition after setting variable Working, condition will be **variable(UpperCaseCol)** contains `toUpper(variables('Working'))`
   - **YES:** create new Append to string variable - Name: **CorrectName**, Value: `concat(' ',toUpper(variables('Working')))`
   - **NO:** moved existed Append action

[image]

Thats everything, Flow will looks like:
[image]

Document names changed:

from:
[image]

to (Ar was not in the UpperCase list, its OK):
[image]

**CHANGES PATH TWO - FIXING LAST WORDS AND '-' before them:**

1. **Move Initialize variable - Working** as first Initializing (you will need it) and fill value with: `replace(triggerBody()?['{Name}'],'-',' - ')` - this will create always '-' with a spaces from both sides (it's the easiest way)
2. **Change Initialize variable NAME** - value: `split(variables('Working'),' ')`
3. Thats everything, it will looks like:

BEFORE:
[image]

AFTER:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Zdenek. I am only looking this to be applicable for certain words in file name. For example, let' s say a file name is: "Monthly Cfo Report Mm Az 1-29-19" then it should be set to Monthly CFO Report MM AZ 1-29-19. Will the above formula account for this change, thanks for the help again.

Comment: So words Monthly and Report in file name should not be converted to MONTHLY and REPORT post running the flow.

Comment: okey, but how you recognize that the CFO or MM is short of something? You probably need some keywords saved somewhere and working with them, after this you need to update this Append to string function.

Comment: Hi Zednek, I received feedback today from the end client and they want to make sure that certain words in file name should not be in upper/lower rather only Upper case. Cfo, Mm are only examples I am giving.

Comment: ok understand, so they want words shorted than 3 symbols to make upperCase only?

Comment: Okay let me reframe this. Currently in production they already have this names in upper case. For example for file name:  97 East CE Jeriff INVESTOR REPORT LLC , so if i run the flow you gave me, it will be converted to 97 East Ce Jeriff Investor Report Llc but instead they want it as : 97 East CE Jeriff Investor Report LLC so that way LLC and CE should be untouched string in file name.

Comment: I understand, I am asking you, if its okay, if I do IF statement in the function for words shorter than 3 words? Because I dont know how in other way do this, do you understand my question? They want to, if it will be at start 83 jeriff INVESTOR Llc make it with flow to : 83 Jeriff Invertor LLC ?

Comment: Hi Zednek, I follow what you are saying, is there any other way to hard code these strings/words used so that way flow doesn't touch it? Coz if we do if statement as you suggested then its going to affect other names as well which might be an issue, for example they have "Of" used in file name then that would also be changed OF. So problematically logic wise this is not possible right?

Comment: Yes this is what I am asking.. so the IF statement we cant do, so how to do it? We can skip words shorter than 3 for the upper,lower case or we need a DICTIONARY words that should be uppercase.

Comment: How can we leverage the Dictionary concept u mentioned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89073/discussion-between-mdevm-and-zdenk-vinduska).

Comment: Zdenek, did you get a chance to review my comment in the chat window.

Comment: Hello, answer edited, added fixing for your problem in CHANGES PATH TWO

Comment: hi, thanks zdenek. Where should the initialize working var action go, right up top? then the value should be set in the value section of initilize variable- working right? not set var, a little confused there.

Comment: Same for initialize var name, value should be changed to the expression that you gave right from within the same action?not set var?

Comment: Have you set this to work? I am in the discussion but you dont go there... Dont forget to mark it as answer thanks